# What are the units of my data after an FFT?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, physical-units

Magnetometer measures the derivative of the magnetic field, or dB/dt, with an  output in microvolts (mV). The Sampling rate is 128 Hz, so if we collect data for 2 minutes, $2 \times 60 \times  128=15360$ points (discrete case). When I perform an FFT on these time series, what will the units of amplitude density be  after the transform?

Comment: Your raw data is in mv vs 1/time thus after FFT  the ordinate still has units of mv and the abscissa units of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: if you directly use the voltage output (here in microvolts), your FFT amplitude should be in **mV** (microvolts) as well. If you have access to the sensor calibration curve to convert units, the FFT amplitude should be in Teslas per second (**T/s**), as you look at a derivative.

If you look at a power density spectrum (squared), then the units above should be squared as well (mV$^2$ or T$^2$/s$^2$).

Now in  general, for a given  unit U, albeit in volt (V), tesla (T), whatever. The FFT sums samples $x_k$ in the original units (U) multiplied by unitless complex values (due to discretization) $e^{-2\pi j\cdot}$. Thus **the units after FFT remain the same as for the original signal, i.e. U**.

If you take the absolute value, the same again. For instance, the $0$-frequency index gives you the DC, or average value of your signal  (or at least it is proportional, with a factor of the number of samples, or its square root depending on the normalization).

**The continuous Fourier transform**, in contrast, "sums" the samples times complex cisoids times a time differential (the $\mathrm{d}t$):
$$\int e^{-2\pi j\cdot}x(t)\mathrm{d}t $$

Its **units would be U.s** (s for seconds). Unless you normalize it by something with a unit, like in

$$\frac{1}{T}\int e^{-2\pi j\cdot}x(t)\mathrm{d}t $$

where to "average" over some period or time span $T$ (in time units), and then the results would have the same units as $x(t)$ again.

Comment: Can you take a look at now,it is dicrete,what should be the amplitude unit?

Comment: Yes I also had problem to grasp this.It should be the voltage from the sensor.