# Units for a PSD from square of FT?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, physical-units

If I am looking to do a PSD plot on a signal $x(t)$ with units $m$ then the units I am expecting in the PSD would be $\frac{m^2}{Hz}$ but I can't seem to get this result from the following reasoning:

If we consider the fourier transform 
$$ F(k) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x(t) e^{-2\pi i k t} dt  $$ 
I think this should have units $ms$ then the PSD should be 
$$|F(k)|^2. $$
Which should have units $m^2s^2$ or $m^2Hz^{-2}$ which is not $\frac{m^2}{Hz}$. There is probably an obvious mistake here but I can't see it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning sounds correct (with unit considerations), you can see a discussion on both continuous and discrete aspects of the Fourier transform in [What are the units of my data after an FFT?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35994/15892)

What is unclear to me is why  you expect the PSD to be in unit $\frac{m^2}{Hz}$? Powers are powers: if a quantity has unit $\textrm{u}$, its square has unit $\textrm{u}^2$. However, when dealing with physics, the quantities you mention are often somehow periodic, and evaluated via averaging over one period, or asymptotically. So basically you had a normalization factor, proportional to the inverse of a time duration, or $\textrm{s}^{-1}$. Hence, possibly, your $\textrm{Hz}$ factor.

Comment: I am trying to recreate someone elses results using the same method and these are the units they use. However I also see these units used often in other places, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) for example

Comment: That's clearer to me now. I have added an explanation